# HW Seems too easy - Overloading equivalency operator as a member and as a non-member function

Tags: c++, dynamic, operator-overloading, cstring, equivalence

The assignment is to create a class that implements a dynamic cstring (null-terminated char array).The default constructor should create an empty array and there should also be an overloaded constructor that creates an array of size n.There should also be a function that will grow the array to a larger size (he said that this should be in the class but we will not utilize it until a later assignment). We're also supposed to create two versions of this class. In one version, we will overload the equivalency operator as a member function, and in the second version, we will overload the equivalency operator as a non-member function.

Something feels weird to me because this just seems way to easy.

For the member version, I set it to return true if the two class sizes were equal.

```
bool CSTR::operator ==(const CSTR & rhs) {

    return (size == rhs.size);
}
```

For the non-member version, I just created a member function to return it's size as an integer and then compare them when the operator is overloaded.

```
bool operator ==(const CSTR2 & CSTR2_1, const CSTR2 & CSTR2_2) {

    return (CSTR2_1.getSize() == CSTR2_2.getSize());
}
```

I'm just kind of terrified to turn this in without any outside input because this solution of mine seems way too simple compared to everything we have been going over in class. I know we are going to expand on this program for a later assignment, but if any of you see anything that I'm missing here, some input would be awesome.

Here is the code I'm trying to use to compare the cstring. Note: there is nothing in the assignment description that says anything about inputting values into the cstrings.

```
#include "CSTR.h"
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;


class CSTR {
    public:
        CSTR();
        CSTR(unsigned int n);
        ~CSTR();


        bool operator ==(const CSTR & rhs);
    private:
        unsigned int size;
        char *elems;

        bool grow(unsigned int newSize);
};

=================================

CSTR::CSTR() {

    size = 0;
    elems = new char [0];
}

CSTR::CSTR(unsigned int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        size = n;
        elems = new char [size];
}
    else {
        size = 0;
        elems = new char [0];
    }
}

CSTR::~CSTR() {

    delete [] elems;
}

bool CSTR::operator ==(const CSTR & rhs) {

    return ((elems == rhs.elems) == 0);
}
```

I've initialized two objects of CSTR with different sizes, and when I test for equivalency it is returning that they are equal.

Comment: A dynamic cstring (aka 0-terminated string) or a dynamic counted string?

Comment: Use `strcmp` to compare to 0-terminated strings. Beside that, you did good.

Comment: Your code only checks if the strings have the same length - presumably you are also meant to check if they have the same characters in them

Comment: Does empty array mean array of length 1 only containing the terminator? Shall buffer size be part of the value? I think not... BTW: Can you use `std::unique_ptr` for storing your buffer?

Comment: Say I initialize one object with a dynamically allocated cstring of size 3, and then I initialize another object with a dynamically allocated cstring of size 4. If I use strcmp on these, is it automatically going to return that they are equal every time? That is what I'm currently getting with strcmp.

Comment: @Deduplicator - It said of size 0

Comment: `strcmp` returns -1 if the left and +1 if the right string is earlier. 0 for equallity. so you need a simple negation: `!`

Comment: @Deduplicator - I added a little more code to the top showing where I'm at with strcmp

Comment: do you want to test for being the same buffer or containing the same string? `a == b`: Same buffer; `!strcmp(a, b)`: Equal string.